# Listings package with caption legend in spanish

Tags: listings, captions, languages

I'm using the `listings` package and would like to translate the caption text displayed to Spanish, so instead of `Listing 1: Dummy label` it will display `Listado 1: Dummy label`.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}   % list options between brackets
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Links
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
%  language=Octave,                % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,           % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,
}



\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Evento celebrado en días no consecutivos]
{
"identificador" : "22587"
"nombre" : "Visita guiada para conocer las aves del Botanico"
"descripcion" : "... Los domingos 8 de julio, 12 de agosto y 9 de septiembre (a las 10.30 horas) ..."
"dia-de-inicio" : "2012-07-08 10:30:00 +0200"
"dia-de-fin" : "2012-09-09 10:30:00 +0200"
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can redefine `\lstlistingname` which is the caption label for listings:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}   % list options between brackets

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Links
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listado}

\lstset{ %
%  language=Octave,                % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,           % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,
}  

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Evento celebrado en días no consecutivos]
{
"identificador" : "22587"
"nombre" : "Visita guiada para conocer las aves del Botanico"
"descripcion" : "... Los domingos 8 de julio, 12 de agosto y 9 de septiembre (a las 10.30 horas) ..."
"dia-de-inicio" : "2012-07-08 10:30:00 +0200"
"dia-de-fin" : "2012-09-09 10:30:00 +0200"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Listing]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Try `\newcaptionname` from the [`scrbase`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) package. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrbase}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcaptionname{spanish}{\lstlistingname}{Listado}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Evento celebrado en días no consecutivos}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Using `\newcaptionname`, you can simultaneously provide translations for all languages supported by the `babel` package.